I changed a default MainActivity
hello I want to change default activity. But when I do that the app doesn't launch at all without any errors
  Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]

I'm trying reset app and changing a code but nothink

How did you change the default activity? I believe you have to set it in the Manifest.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Specify following in the manifest for the activity:
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>

